# Remove or change original data from stream Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a code to write a hash to the file from text of another file, but the problem is that in resulting file is written not only hash, but also the original text.

For example: if content of source file `qwerty` a got in result file `qwertyd8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4`, but i need just `d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4`.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hash = crypto.createHash('MD5');

const readData = fs.createReadStream('./task1/input.txt');
const writeData = fs.createWriteStream('./task1/output.txt');

readData.on('data', (chunk) => {
    hash.update(chunk);
});

readData.on('end', () => {
    const resultHash = hash.digest('hex');
    writeData.end(resultHash);
    console.log(resultHash);
});

readData.pipe(writeData);
```

How i can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Why `md5` ?????

Comment: `readData.pipe(writeData);` <- that writes your input to your output. May remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hash a stream, thats super easy as `hash` is itself a stream ( a Transform stream). Just pipe your input into it, and pipe the resulting hash into your output:

```
 const fs = require('fs');
 const crypto = require('crypto');
 const hash = crypto.createHash('MD5');

  const readData = fs.createReadStream('./task1/input.txt');
 const writeData = fs.createWriteStream('./task1/output.txt');

 readData.pipe(hash).pipe(writeData);
```

[Reference](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash)

Comment: Elegant  @Jonas W.

Comment: oh, all ingenious is simple. Thanks)